# Dynamic EnumDropDownList

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, enums, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a set of Enums for Countries and States in a static Enum model.

```
 public static class Enums
 {
    public enum Countries
    {
        [Display(Name = "Afghanistan")]
        AFG,
        [Display(Name = "United States")]
        USA
    }
    public static class States
    {
        public enum USStates
        {
            [Display(Name = "Alabama")]
            AL,
            [Display(Name = "New York")]
            NY
        }
        public enum NoStates
        {

        }
    }
    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetStatesByCountryId(int id)
    {
        Enums.Countries Country = (Enums.Countries)id;
        switch (Country)
        { 
            case Countries.AFG:
                return null;
            case Countries.USA:
                return Enum.GetValues(typeof(States.USStates)).Cast<States.USStates>().Select(v => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = v.ToString(),
                    Value = ((int)v).ToString()
                });

        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

IndexModel (my view data):

```
public class IndexModel
{
    public Enums.Countries Countries { get; set; }
    public Enums.States.USStates States { get; set; }

    public IndexModel()
    {
        Countries = new Enums.Countries();
        States = new Enums.States.USStates();
    }
}
```

HomeController:

```
    public JsonResult GetStatesForCountry(string id)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id))
        {
            int CountryId = 0;
            bool Success = Int32.TryParse(id, out CountryId);
            if (Success)
            {
                return Json(Enums.GetStatesByCountryId(CountryId), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

View:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('select#Countries').change(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("GetStatesForCountry", "Home")",
            data: { id: $(this).val() },
            success: function (retVal) {
                $('select#States').val(retVal);
            },
            error: function (){

            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.Countries)
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.States, "Please Select")
```

This all seems to work great, surprisingly.  I just wired it up and it worked out ok.  However, my model is bound to this USStates type, so my question:

How do I structure this so this EnumDropDownList's type isn't tied to USStates?  What I need is an object, where I can change the enums that it is tied to, but I don't know how to do this.  Could I use ViewBag to handle delivering the data so it's not bound to a type?  Can someone show an example?  I've only been developing for a few months now, and I'd very much appreciate any help.

This was really what I was asking before I mass-editted and butchered my original question.  I was hoping not to rely on JQuery, but I don't think there's anyway around that.

Comment: From where did you get **EnumDropDownListFor**, did you make this your own html helper or download some nuget package for it?

Comment: It's a built-in helper in 5.2.0-rc but started in 5.1.

Comment: Is there anyway to possible create a Partial view that takes in an Enum type, and tell the EnumDropDownListFor(m => Model)?  It would be easy to tell javascript to pass in a partial view

Comment: You're probably better off storing states and countries as classes and in the DB instead of an enum. Countries change, states change. It's easier to add them into the DB than dig through your code.